# Get List of Categories on the basis of foreign model in django

Tags: django, django-filter

I've two models as below.

```
class Category(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=55)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'Food Category'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Food Categories'

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

class FoodItem(TimeStampWithCreator):
    CATEGORY_CHOICES = (
        ('takeway', 'Takeaway'),
        ('dine_in', 'Dine In'),
        ('function', 'Function'),
    )
    type_menu_select = models.CharField(max_length=20, choices=CATEGORY_CHOICES, default='takeway')
    category = models.ForeignKey(FoodCategory, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

i want to filter all the categories containing takeaway, I've no idea how to achieve this

Comment: You have 2 types of "category" so your question is confusing. Are you asking for all `Category` with a `FoodItem` that have `type_menu_select` set to `'takeway'`?  (there's a missing 'a' in there, btw)

Answer (score 0):

You've included category choices in your FoodItem model but the model also has a ForeignKey to a Category model, this isn't needed if the only category objects you have are those three choices (the category field must refer to one of those anyway as it's the ForeignKey). To filter the items by category you would need to use a queryset filter.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/db/queries/#retrieving-specific-objects-with-filters

```py
FoodItem.objects.filter(category=YourCategory)
```

Answer (score 0):

This is usually the kind of thing I'd like to test in the shell as I don't do it very often.  If what you want is actually all `Category` with a `FoodItem` that have `type_menu_select` set to `'takeway'` then the following should work (but I haven't tested it):

```py
Category.objects.filter(fooditem__type_menu_select='takeway')
```

This is using the ["reverse" relationship on the ForeignKey and there's more information in the Django docs (search for 'reverse')](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/topics/db/queries/#lookups-that-span-relationships).